# What VS Code API can I use to create an in-editor chat box like in GitHub Copilot Chat?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

What VS Code API is used for creating webiviews as the one below?

I am trying to create a similar prompt which get activated when a code snipped is selected and allow user to prompt some commands.

[image]

The box in the screenshot says:

> Ask Copilot or type '/' for commands (Ctrl+UpArrow, Ctrl+DownArrow for history)

It also has a button that says "View in Chat", and another that says "Cancel".

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this is the https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vscode-dts/vscode.proposed.interactive.d.ts API proposal. If you [download the extension VSIX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot-chat), rename the filename extension from vsix to zip, unzip it, and grep its source code for "Ask Copilot or", then you'll see the `this.inputPlaceholder=...`, which is a property of `InteractiveSession`, and other parts of that API proposal being used near the same code, including `provideSlashCommands` and `saveState`.

The proposed APIs that I see being used in the current latest Copilot Chat extension at the time of this writing (version 0.8.2023092902) are: `interactive`,
`interactiveUserActions`,
`chatProvider`,
`chatSlashCommands`,
`readonlyMessage`,
`chatVariables`,
`mappedEditsProvider`,
`aiRelatedInformation`,
and `chatAgents`.

You can find the full current list of API proposal interfaces at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/src/vscode-dts, and related docs at https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/using-proposed-api.

---

You may also be interested in the proposed API for contributing chat agents: [Chat agent API #199908](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/199908).

Comment: Given that these are proposed APIs, how is copilot using them in non-insider builds?

Comment: @Wesley beats me. but it's a Microsoft extension, and Microsoft owns VS Code, so I'm not surprised that they can skirt around whatever limitations they place.